# Limitations of the conditional operator ?:

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, destructor, operator-keyword, conditional-operator

I am using GCC 4.5 and have observed very peculiar behavior. I am wondering if there is something with this operator that I do not completely understand. I thought I was proficient in C++.
I have a thin C++ wrapper class `Wnd` for Windows `HWND` objects with an implemented cast operator `operator HWND ...`.

If I use the conditional operator like this (given input `Wnd *p` and a sample function `SetParent(HWND))`:

```
SetParent((p!=NULL) ? (HWND)(*p) : NULL)
```

The parent is properly set to `NULL` or `p` depending. This is what I would expect.
However if dare to be lazy and write:

```
SetParent(p ? *p : NULL)
```

things go haywire. 
After running GDB I find that destructor is called on variable `p` after the call to `SetParent`.
Any ideas what is going on here?

**Edit**
Here is my Wnd class:

```
class Wnd{
        HWND m_hwnd;        ///< the actual handle
        WndFake *fake;      ///< store state here if we do not have a handle
    public:
        virtual ~Wnd();
        //contructor s
        Wnd(HWND wnd=NULL):m_hwnd(wnd),fake(NULL){}
        Wnd(DWORD sty,const jchar *title,const RECT &sz);
        operator HWND(){return m_hwnd;}
        operator HWND() const {return m_hwnd;}
    }
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to show your complete `Wnd` class definition.

Comment: @bacchus, note your `(HWND))` edit was wrong :D though the improved spacing is nice...

Comment: @sarnold  The extra bracket is from the sentence. I missed that. Thank you for the warning ;)

Comment: @orion93 Does `SetParent((p) ? (*p) : NULL)` still cause problems?

Comment: Please provide the definition of `Wnd`.  Without it, this question is wholly unanswerable.

Comment: -1. Its bad a question. One should learn to post relevant code when asking a question.

Comment: Appologies for not submitting the code. This is some very helpful advice. I have made edit to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your Wnd has non-explicit conversion constructor too that takes HWND or even int?
If so then make it explicit.

Your Wnd probably does not have copy constructor and operator= declared? declare these private and don't define them.

Also remove `operator HWND` and add member function `HWND hwnd() const;` to your Wnd. Then the code will look readable like:

```
Setparent( p ? p->hwnd() : NULL );
```

I trust that when these mods are done you will find out what is wrong with your Wnd.

The problem manifests itself because the operands at both sides of : in ?: have to be of same type so NULL (0) is somehow convertible to Wnd. So the temporary copy of *p is made as return value of ?: then operator HWND is called to it.

Comment: +1 I think that removal of the implicit conversion from `HWND` to `Wnd` should do the trick, as that disables the conversion from `NULL` to `Wnd` and the compiler will be forced to convert in the opposite direction. At any rate you are completely right that removing implicit conversions will make code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

Is the destructor called on variable p or on some temporary variable that is a copy of p?

In your first example you are using c-style cast to convert `*p` to a `HWND`. In the second, you are letting the compiler do the conversion, and that might well involve making a copy of `*p`.

Answer (score 2):

The operands of `?:` operator must be brought to common type, which will be used at the result. When you use

```
SetParent(p != NULL ? (HWND) *p : NULL);
```

you essentially manually force the situation, when the compiler has choose the common type to be `HWND`. I.e. the above variant is equivalent to

```
SetParent(p != NULL ? (HWND) *p : (HWND) NULL);
```

But when you do

```
SetParent(p != NULL ? *p : NULL);
```

the rules of the language work differently, the compiler will decide the common type differently. In this the common type is not `HWND`, but your `Wnd`. Both operands are converted to `Wnd` and the latter variant is interpreted as

```
SetParent(p != NULL ? *p : Wnd(NULL));
```

I.e. when `p` is null the compiler constructs a temporary object `Wnd(NULL)` (using the conversion constructor you provided) and returns it as the result. Moreover, the compiler will most likely construct a temporary object in the true branch too (by using the copy constructor). The resultant temporary object is then converted to `HWND` type (since that is what `SetParent` requires), so the whole thing is interpreted as

```
SetParent((HWND) (p != NULL ? Wnd(*p) : Wnd(NULL)));
```

The temporary object is then destroyed immediately after the call to `SetParent`. This is the destruction that you observed, except that you incorrectly interpreted it as the destruction of `p`.

The reason the compiler can choose this approach is because your conversion constructor is not declared `explicit`. If you declare the conversion constructor `explicit`

```
class Wnd {
  ...
  explicit Wnd(HWND wnd=NULL) : m_hwnd(wnd), fake(NULL) {}
  ...
};
```

the compiler will no longer be able to use to implicitly convert `NULL` to `Wnd`. In that case the compiler will be left with no choice but to use `HWND` as a common type instead

```
SetParent(p != NULL ? (HWND) *p : (HWND) NULL);
```

just like you wanted it to.

P.S. When you already have `operator HWND() const` in your class, there's no point in implementing the identical non-const version `operator HWND()`.